# When deleting repeated iptables rules, in what order are they deleted?

Tags: iptables, firewall

Let's suppose I have some repeated iptables rules:

```
$ iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j DROP
```

And I want to delete one by one with:

$ iptables -D FORWARD -j DROP

In what order are the rules deleted in this way? Is the first rule or the last rule in the chain that are deleted using **-D** option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems easy enough to test.  Let's create a a set of rules:

```
[root@fedora ~]# iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP
[root@fedora ~]# iptables -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT
[root@fedora ~]# iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP
[root@fedora ~]# iptables -S FORWARD
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j DROP
```

If we run `iptables -D FORWARD -j DROP`, which one gets deleted?

```
[root@fedora ~]# iptables -D FORWARD -j DROP
[root@fedora ~]# iptables -S FORWARD
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j DROP
```

It looks like it deleted the first one.